# Binary Search conditions

Tags: search, binary-search

When solving a search problem with binary search, sometimes the loop condition is while `low < hi` and sometimes it is while `low <= hi`.

I try to alternate between these two based on the output I get, but I want to have a better intuition of how to distinguish between two and know when to use which condition.

What is an easy way to choose which condition to use?

Comment: Also posted at [computer science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/99948/binary-search-conditions). Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, you may flag to request migration.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these approaches should ideally solve the problem correctly if properly implemented. Personally I like to follow the `low <= hi` approach.

Pseudo Code :

```
while(low <= hi){
    int mid = (low + hi)/2;
    if(check condition for mid){
       result = mid;
       hi = mid - 1; or low = mid + 1;
    }else{
       low = mid + 1; or hi = mid - 1;
    }
}
```

In the above code we check if mid satisfy's the condition of a possible answer to our solution and based on that move either to the left or the right subsequence. Also note that the movement to the left or the right subsequence depends on whether we want to find the maxima or minima for the problem.